# Is there a better way to make this splash screen layout?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I had been thinking about to how to make this simple layout:

[image]

The solution that I came up looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                height: 75,
                width: 75,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('App name'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text('Copyright'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure if there is a more elegant way to center the "Logo Image" (The red container), with the "App name text" below it, and having at the same time, on the bottom of the screen, the "Copyright text".

I've tried to build the layout using a Column widget, but the Align widget don't make any change in the position of the "Copyright text":

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              height: 75,
              width: 75,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text('App name'),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('Copyright'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That give me the next result:

[image]

So... Is there a better way to make this splash screen layout? Maybe there is a widget that is the right one for when you want to place elements in both the center and the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Positioned layout outside the column but inside the stack like this:

```
Positioned( bottom:0,
            child: Align( alignment: Alignment.center, 
                       child:Text("Copyright"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want just use Column without Stack,you can put two Containers in Column and wrap them in Expanded widget like code below:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            height: 75,
            width: 75,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('App name'),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Copyright'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea, using `Spacer()` instead of the Expanded widget is more simple, I think.

Comment: that's right but when I use `Spacer()` all objects align to left of screen